# How to have current date and time on csh prompt?

Tags: shell, scripting, csh

I am trying to put the current date and time in csh prompt. The same is working for bash.

If the prompt is written "`date`", it is not updating when finishing the command. When written '`date`', there is a `date` string in the terminal.

[The experiment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZDjt.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
set prompt='%w %D %Y %P %# '
```

will work with tcsh.

The original C shell does almost no interpretation inside its prompt variable. You can work around this in some cases I don't think that you can achieve what you want with the original csh.

UPDATE: setting the prompt is much more flexible using precmd - this is a "command" that gets executed every time before the prompt is shown. You can alias it to whatever you like. For example:

```
alias precmd set prompt='"`date`"'
```

will update properly. Since this uses date to set the prompt I assume it will respect time zone settings.

You can change date to whatever you wish!

Comment: It is just not showing time in my time zone

Comment: edited my answer to include a better and more flexible solution that should display proper time

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, i did not express my thoughts correctly.

set prompt='%w %D %Y %P %# '  works correctly, it is just showing the timezone of the server I am working on. But I have already found a way to make prompt show my local time zone.

Thank you very much for your support.